# Applying the Same 'Aggregated Key' in Terms Aggregation on array for 'Include' Parameter in Filters

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have 2 types of data within a single elastic index as given below.

```
{ "item_cd.keyword": "100", "sum": 5, "data_type": 1 }
{ "item_cd": [100, 101, 102],  "data_type": 2 }
```

I want to aggregate the data by using the item_cd. By using the query below I was able to achieve that

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "filtered_aggregation": {
      "aggs": {
        "unique_items": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "item_cd.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_aggregation": {
              // sum aggregation here
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem is, that I want to return only the "item_cd" from "data_type 1". But I am getting the 101 and 102 in the results. I can use the "include" keyword within terms to filter out the results to a specific one, But we don't have the value with us as this query gets executed dynamically.

Is there any way to give item_cd.keyword from data_type1 into the "INCLUDE" keyword?

Comment: Could you please give an example of running directly on a console? These two different documents why have two different fields, `item_cd` and `item_cd.keyword`.